# Numpy retrieve a range of elements from a given set of indexes

Tags: python

Lets say we have a numpy `array = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]`. If you want to change the elements with `index = [1,3,5]` in this array you can simply call `array[index]` which will give you an array of the elements `[11,13,15]`.

Now if we still have `array = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]` and I want to pick out a sequence of, ex. length 2, of numbers in this array based on a array of `index = [1,3,5]`, is there a nice way in  numpy to do this by doing something like `array[index:(index+2)]` returning `[[11,12],[13,14],[15,16]]`? I could obviously do this easily with for-loops but I wonder if there is a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
array[index.reshape(-1,1) + np.arange(2)]
```

The argument to `arange()` determines how many elements to take starting from each index, and it's OK if they overlap.  For example with `arange(4)` the result is:

```
  [[11, 12, 13, 14],
   [13, 14, 15, 16],
   [15, 16, 17, 18]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way:

```
array = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
index = [1, 3, 5]
count = 2
[array[num:num + count] for num in index]
```